# If a page does not connect to a database can it have an output to return

Tags: php, exception

Originally using PHP, when I test the connection to the database, I see it up to do the following

```
if (empty($this->_db)) { return; }
```

but the problem I have right now is that when this part of my page does not  connect to the database then my page does not load. Can I have something like this

```
if (empty($this->_db))
{
    $output .= "<!-- NOTICE WHEN DB SERVER IS DOWN -->";
    $output .= '<dt><a href="http://someurl.php">Contact Us</a></dt>';
    $output .= '<dd>We are currently updating our server. Please check back at a later time.</dd>';
    return $output;
}
```

I know I could test this but I want it to know if there is any proper syntax and/or a more accurate way to set this up.

Comment: Yes that is fine. Your code could be better but that would work.

Comment: @Fuser97381 what would you change from my code? This is kind of why I asked the question, trying to improve my coding.

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine. You might also want to return a 503 (Temporarily unavailable) so if google bot catches you offguard it doesn't screw you.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Retry-After: 300');//300 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If something fundamental like the database does not work, you should throw an exception. You should then have a global exception handler which outputs a nice error page. This global exception handler could be set in your PHP code, or it could simply be configured in the web server so that any time the PHP script errors out, the web server will serve a specific page.

If you get into dependency injected object oriented programming with exceptions, such problems require relatively little code and problems at any stage will find their way to an appropriate error handler. You should most certainly not intersperse a bunch of `if (..)` checks all throughout your code to handle such global error conditions.